# Is the Euler characteristic of aspherical connected 2-complexes at most 1? (No!)  What can be said about subcomplexes of 2-complexes deformation retractible onto graphs.

Tags: euler-characteristics, simplicial-complexes, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory

I have several related questions, i do not know which one is more important to me, i think it would depend on their answers.

1. Is it true that the Euler characteristic of a finite connected aspherical simplicial 2-complex cannot be greater than 1?
2. If $A$ is a finite simplicial 2-complexe that retracts by deformation onto a graph (1-complex), is it true that every subcomplex of $A$ is aspherical?
3. (This is the question that i am most likely interested in.) If $A$ is as above, is it true that every connected subcomplex $B$ of $A$ is of Euler characteristic at most 1, and if the Euler characteristic of $B$ is 1, then $B$ is contractible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer concerns Question 1. Take a free group on $2$ generators and $k$ very long relations at random. Then, with high probability, the representation satisfies a small cancellation condition and the associated 2-complex $X$ is aspherical. Moreover, if this happens you also have $\chi(X) = k-1$.

A negative answer to Question 2 would also be a negative answer to [Whitehead's Asphericity Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_conjecture). I believe that a positive answer is not easy to obtain either.

Concerning Question 3: If $X \subset Y$ are 2-complexes, then the induced map $H_2(X) \to H_2(Y)$ is injective. This follows from the long exact sequence in homology. If $Y$ deformation retracts onto a 1-complex, then this implies that $H_2(X)=0$ and hence $\chi(X) \leq 1$ if $X$ is connected. I do not see how $\chi(X)=1$ could imply that $X$ is contractible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andreas, i should have thought of it!  I am however still mostly interested in question 3.

Comment: I understood that there would be no negative answer to 2.  You have answered the question from the title, so i would have to mark it as answered, but i am afraid that then people wouldn't look at question 3, so i cheated and changed the title :).

Comment: No problem. Question 3 is interesting.

Comment: I've decided to post Question 3 separately:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87342/acyclic-subcomplexes-of-a-2-complexes-deformation-retractible-onto-graphs-are-th

Answer (score 0):

About Question 3, thanks to Andreas' answer it is enough to prove that there is no acyclic 2-complex $X$ with $\pi_1(X)=D\pi_1(X)\neq\lbrace0\rbrace$.

Indeed it would mean that $\chi(B)=1 \implies$ $B$ is weakly contractible $\overset{Whitehead}{\implies}$ $B$ is contractible.

I have no examples in mind, all I can say is that making a loop into a commutator amounts to make it bound the complementary of a disk in a torus, this is how I would go for a counterexample.

Comment: Hi Arnaud, what is $D\pi_1(X)$?

Comment: Unfortunately there exists acyclic 2-complexes which are not contractible, so this approach won't work.

Comment: @Jesper Grodal: can you point me to an example of an acyclic non contractible 2-complex, please?  By the way, i do not see why the subcomplex $B$ will be acyclic, i only see that $H_1(B)$ will be finite.

Comment: Sorry about the silly question: of course, if it is acyclic but $\pi_1$ is nontrivial, it is not contractible.  I do not see though an easy example.

Comment: It has been explained to me by a colleague why $B$ will be acyclic: $H_1(B)$ with coefficients in any $\mathbb Z_p$ has to be trivial, not only with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Jesper Gordal : here we assume that $\chi(B)=1$. If you still know such examples which are not contractible, then it is an answer to Alexey's question. 

@Alexey : Still thinking of a counterexample, put $X=\mathbb{T}^2\setminus\mathbb{D}^2$, a torus minus a little disc, and $X_0:=X$. Then to each of the two obvious generators of $\pi_1(X0)$, glue a copy of $X$ along its boundary : this forms $X_1$. Repeating this process we obtain an inductive limit which is a CW-complex with every chance to be a counterexample.